# The number of delete votes is shown to the left

Tags: bug, status-completed, mobile-web

In the mobile theme, the number of votes to delete a post is shown to the left side, instead of the usual right side.

> [image: question]

> [image: answer]

This happens with both iOS 6, and OS X 10.8, using the default browser they come with.

Comment: The same happens on Android 4.3, default browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been fixed and will be available in the next deployment (`rev 2245` on meta and `rev 1606` on the network).